# What is the consequence of setting convert_urls to false in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

The [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/url-handling/#convert_urls) for "convert_urls" says you can set this to true if you want TinyMCE to be "smart" because otherwise URLs are "messed up" and there is "no way to get the real URL" otherwise.

What does all this mean in practice?  What is the real problem if I use convert_urls=false?  What is going to get "messed up" and/or lost?